# Line Break in <div>-elements (while float:left)

Tags: html, css

I'm having the following problem:
I have 3 < div >-elements. 2 of those I want to display on the same line, while the other one needs to be a new line.

I use float:left for the first 2-< div >'s, but I'm not able to produce the third < div > on a new line.

Fiddle for you convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/D3Exr/

Now i have:

```
 abcdefghijklmnop
```

While i actually want:

```
 abcdefghijk
 lmnop
```

Thank you!

Comment: I hope now the clear property it's more clear to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clear:both;` to fix it.

I suggest you to rely on the Mozilla Developers Network documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them.

Also to understand how to use clear:

> **left** The element is moved down to clear past left floats. 
>   **right** The element is moved down to clear past right floats. 
>   **both** The element is moved down to clear past both left and right floats.

In your example you used float:left; for those 2 divs, so you could use either `clear:left` or `clear:both` to clear your floated divs.

**DEMO**:

http://jsfiddle.net/D3Exr/8/

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear: left;` to your last div.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D3Exr/1/)

Just add `clear:both;` or `clear:left;` to the third `div`

it makes no floating elements allowed on the left or the right side of the that `div`

[more info..](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/D3Exr/2/)

use      `clear:both`. It will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by adding `clear: left` to your last division element.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `clear: left` to your last div.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D3Exr/7/

More information on clear:  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

[**working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/D3Exr/9/)

```
<div style="float:left; background-color:green;">abcdef</div>
<div style="float:left; background-color:red;">ghijk</div>
<div style="background-color:yellow; display:block; clear:both;">lmnop<div>
```